# update mysql table column of timestamp without changing any field

Tags: mysql, sql

How can we update timestamp in table without any updation
without below statement

```
update table_name set field_name1 = 1 where field_name =1;
```

and i have added image of table structure

[image]

Comment: The timestamp field can be just another field - just like the order_id etc... but it can also be set to be auto-updating. Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html for the 5.0 docs which clarify that behaviour was different in earlier editions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot update without using `UPDATE`.

For timestamp columns, read the MySQL docs: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

> If the column is auto-updated, it is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. The column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent the column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value.
>
> **To update the column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example, set it to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)**.

So, update the timestamp column only:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET last_delv_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE ... ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET columnNAME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE columnName = ???
```

edit:

or change your table structur to:

```
ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```